# Forbidden: /api/v1.0/user/create-user/ & { "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided." } DJANGO

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, createuser

I was creating Login functionality for my Python Django backend, "create user" functionality was working fine before. But then after Login was entirely coded, the create-user stopped working.

My urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import TestView, UserView, UserLoginView
from rest_framework_jwt.views import refresh_jwt_token, verify_jwt_token

urlpatterns = [
    path('test', TestView.as_view()),
    path('create-user/', UserView.as_view()),
    path('get-user', UserLoginView.as_view()),
    path('login-user/', UserLoginView.as_view()),
]
```

My views.py file:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate


class TestView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        print("API called")
        return Response("You did it!", status=200)


class UserView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        print("Creating User")

        user_data = request.data
        print(request.data)

        user_serializer = UserSerializer(data=user_data)

        if user_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=False):
            user_serializer.save()
            return Response({'user': user_serializer.data}, status=200)

        return Response({'msg': "error: no user created"}, status=400)


class UserLoginView(APIView):

    # convert user token to user data

    def get(self, request, format=None):

        if request.user.is_authenticated == False or request.user.is_active == False:
            return Response('Invalid credentials', status=403)

        user = UserSerializer(request.user)
        print(user.data)

        return Response("Testing", status=200)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        print("Login class")

        # Looking for user's email or username
        user_obj = User.objects.filter(email=request.data['email']).first(
        ) or User.objects.filter(username=request.data['username']).first()

        # if user is valid, returns user data in credentials
        if user_obj is not None:
            credentials = {
                'username': user_obj.username,
                'password': request.data['password']
            }
            user = authenticate(**credentials)

        # if user is valid and active, logs user in
            if user and user.is_active:
                user_serializer = UserSerializer(user)
                return Response("Login successful", user_serializer.data, status=200)

        return Response("Invalid credentials", status=403)
```

My serializers.py file:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueValidator
from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    email = serializers.EmailField(
        required=True,
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
    )

    username = serializers.CharField(
        required=True,
        max_length=32,
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
    )

    first_name = serializers.CharField(
        required=True,
        max_length=32
    )

    last_name = serializers.CharField(
        required=True,
        max_length=32
    )

    password = serializers.CharField(
        required=True,
        min_length=8,
        write_only=True
    )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    def get_token(self, obj):
        jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
        jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER
        payload = jwt_payload_handler(obj)
        token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
        return token

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'token',
            'username',
            'password',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'id'
        )
```

My project's settings.py file:

```
"""
Django settings for AIOHA_backend project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import datetime

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-8dz4fx@zy9&parzic^-v5%*r^w^fncmjtd2my1b)(c-e0bgs8^'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'userAPI',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'AIOHA_backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'AIOHA_backend.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
}

JWT_AUTH = {
    # how long the original token is valid for
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=3),
    # allow refreshing of tokens
    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True,
}
```

Postman Request:

[image]

I get the same for when I tried to log in an existing user, after which I tried creating a new one, thinking I had forgotten the password.

Command Line looks like this:

[image]

What am I missing or doing wrong? Please guide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `permission_classes` in `UserView`. It should contain `AllowAny` so that the api without authentication is allowed.

```
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny

class UserView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        ...
```